# fish shell (условные конструкции if else)

Tags: fish-shell

Есть функция __changes_for_the_specified_date которая должна выводить информацию в зависимости от параметров.

```
function __changes_for_the_specified_date --description '1 аргумент -тип файла ("*.log"), 2 аргумент - дата (2020-11-13), 3 аргумент - выводимое количество (10)'  
   
   if [(count $argv) -eq 1];
      find . -type f -newerat $argv[1]

   else if [(count $argv) -eq 2];
      find . -type f -newerat $argv[1] | tail -n$argv[2]
   
   else if [ (count $argv) -eq 3];
      find ./ -name $argv[1] -type f -newerat $argv[2] | tail -n$argv[3]

end
```

Но при вводе

1. if c 1 аргументом выдаёт ошибку:

   ```
   __changes_for_the_specified_date 2020-11-11
   ~/.config/fish/functions/__changes_for_the_specified_date.fish (line 1): Missing end to balance this function definition
   function __changes_for_the_specified_date --description '1 аргумент -тип файла ("*.log"), 2 аргумент - дата (2020-11-13), 3 аргумент - выводимое количество (10)'
   ^
   from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/functions/__changes_for_the_specified_date.fish
   in command substitution
   source: Error while reading file “/home/xxx/.config/fish/functions/__changes_for_the_specified_date.fish”
   find: The ‘-newerat’ test needs an argument
   ```

   но если просто ввести в консоль `find . -type f -newerat 2020-11-11`, то всё работает верно 
   пробовал для условия if заменить `$argv[1]` на `$argv`, но не сработало
2. else if c 2 аргументоми, не чего не выводит:
   `__changes_for_the_specified_date 2020-11-11 10`
3. else c 3 аргументоми, работает правильно:
   `__changes_for_the_specified_date "*.log" 2020-11-11 10`

почему не срабатывает первые два условия?

Comment: не пользуюсь fish'ем, но почти наверняка `count $argv` (если это корректный синтаксис) выводит `2`, когда задан `1` аргумент: нулевым является имя функции/скрипта... и ещё почти наверняка не хватает `end`'а для `if`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer На сколько я знаю в fish массив начинается с 1 в () это корректный синтаксис. end для if на сколько я знаю не нужен, по крайне мере в данном контексте.

Comment: по первому — предлагаю добавить отладочную печать ради проверки... про `end` — хз, но похоже именно на это жалуется в ошибке... а ещё если `[` — это команда `test`, а не какая-то встроенная конструкция, то после неё нужен пробел...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fat-Zer бал прав про end, end важен! Но главная проблема была в порядке выполнения. Вот рабочий вариант.

function __changes_for_the_specified_date

```
if [(count $argv) -eq 3 ];
   find ./ -name $argv[1] -type f -newerat $argv[2] | tail -n$argv[3]    
else if [(count $argv) -eq 2 ];
   find . -type f -newerat $argv[1] | tail -n$argv[2]   
else
   find . -type f -newerat $argv[1]

end
end
```

Так же я нашёл другое решение:

```
function __changes_for_the_specified_date 

if set -q argv[3]
   find . -name $argv[3] -type f -newerat $argv[1] | tail -n$argv[2] | sort -r    
else if set -q argv[2]
   find . -type f -newerat $argv[1] | tail -n$argv[2] | sort -r    
else if  set -q argv[1]    
    find . -type f -newerat $argv[1] | sort -r    
else
   echo "Вы не ввели аргументы. Введите дату (yyyy-mm-dd) или дату (yyyy-mm-dd) и количество выводимых строк (10), или дату (yyyy-mm-dd) количество строк (10) и расширение ("*.log")."
  
end
end
```

Не уверен что это самые оптимальные варианты но они работают!